# Noughts and Crosses

Tags: python

I'm struggling to get my function to tell the user that the coordinates they have entered are already occupied. I've tried but not sure how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
def CheckValidMove(XCoordinate, YCoordinate, Board):
    ValidMove = True
    # Check x coordinate is valid
    if (XCoordinate < 1) or (XCoordinate > 3):
        ValidMove = False
    # Check y coordinate is valid
    elif(YCoordinate < 1) or (YCoordinate > 3):
        ValidMove = False
        if (Board == XCoordinate and YCoordinate):
            ValidMove = False
    return ValidMove
```

Comment: `Board == XCoordinate and YCoordinate` makes no sense. It is comparing the whole board with a Boolean combination of two integers. What is that supposed to mean? Presumably `Board` is something like a list of lists (you failed to specify). If this is so, then you need to compare the value of `Board[XCoordinate][YCoordinate]` with whatever it is that you use to mark it as occupied (which is again something that you failed to specify).

Comment: Also, note that with the current indentation of your code, you only test this if the test on Y coordinates failed, which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: As a hint, there is no reason that this function requires more that 1 line of code. You could just have `return ______ and _______ and ________` (where the blanks are filled in appropriately). If something evaluates to `True` or `False` you don't need an `if ... else` to return `True` or `False`. Just return the Boolean expression.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you have created your board, here I used a 2d array. with the non-played value at 0 then change it to x or o when played.

```
board = [
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, "x"]
]


def validmove(row, col):
    if 0 <= row < 3 and 0<= col <3:
        return (board[row][col] == 0)
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: You have removed error checking, so this solution could raise an exception, also the `moveValid` variable is a pointless waste of space.